# Facebook connect log out still showing user

Tags: php, facebook, cookies

I am using the following code and it's v strange - when i log out, if i try to actually go back into facebook i cannot but my code below does not register that i'm logged out and will show my facebook user id still

```
include '/home/php_/lib/fb_libs/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '123456789',
  'secret' => 'abcdefghilk',
  'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

echo "user id is $user"; 

if ($user){

    try { $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me'); }

    catch (FacebookApiException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }
}

if ($user)
{
    $logoutURL = $facebook->getLogoutURL();
    echo "<a href='$logoutURL'>Log out </a>";
}

else 
{
    $loginURL = $facebook->getLoginURL(array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_friendslists'
    ));
    echo "<a href='$loginURL'>Log in </a>";
}
```

I understand there are other methods e.g. FB.getLoginStatus() so this is not a duplicate question but why, when this is on github facebook SDK, does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

I think your cookie is causing the problem try not setting the cookie.

Comment: Try to add session_destroy(); because there is really no other way i can think of that remembers your login.